# What is `macros` in clickhouse and what is use of `macros` in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

What are `macros` in Clickhouse?

What is the use-case of `macros` in Clickhouse?

```
<macros>
    <cluster>MyFirstCluster</cluster>
    <replica>chdw1-5</replica>
    <shard>5</shard>
</macros>
```

What is the meaning of each attribute in the config?

What is the best practice in assigning each attribute in the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are for Replicated engines ZK path.

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replication/#creating-replicated-tables

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    EventDate DateTime,
    CounterID UInt32,
    UserID UInt32,
    ver UInt16
) ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{layer}-{shard}/table_name', '{replica}', ver)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(EventDate)
ORDER BY (CounterID, EventDate, intHash32(UserID))
SAMPLE BY intHash32(UserID)
```

Each CH node is independent and is not aware about clustering/sharding/replication.

But Replicated* engines use ZK paths for Replication (to identify themselves as replicas). This ZK path are rendered from macros.

So in your case instead of

```
ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster}/tables/{shard}/table_name', '{replica}', ver)
```

In reality macro will be substituted.

Comment: I am aware that for zookeeper is for coordinating the Clickhouse cluster but I don't get the `macros` variable (especially `layer`)
what is the best practice in defining `macros` variable e,g if we want to have a Clickhouse cluster with `X` shard and 'Y' replication how we should define `macros variable

Comment: You can define own macros. I think you need two different shard macros {myshard1} , {myshard2}. Set both on each node. Then create tables with different macros.

Comment: If I find correctly for each machine in the cluster we need to define different `macro.xml` for showing the role of that machine in the cluster.
Am I correct?